# What is the meaning of *sides* in this conversation?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Customer went to restaurant.

> Bartender : What d'you want, baby?
>
> Customer: Give me a basket, please.
>
> Bartender: **Sides**?
>
> Customer: l don't know yet. Still thinking about it. Trying to watch
>   my figure.

What is the meaning of *sides* in this conversation?

Comment: Is this the complete joke? If not, it's likely that the joke will be based on the double meaning of sides as "side dishes" and "sides of a basket".

Comment: For reference, the conversation was quoted from the movie [Precious (2009)](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/M50104dcce/Precious/-+What+d%27you+want%2C+baby%3F+-+Give+me+a+basket%2C+please.), if it can add more context to the question.

Comment: There isn't any joke of the "so a guy walks into a bar" variety. [The scene takes place at a fried chicken restaurant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKtxpN9hhZU&list=RDeKtxpN9hhZU#t=0), not a bar. If there's a joke, it's self-deprecating, as Precious is a large girl (and pregnant, though I'm not sure how far along).

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/side#Noun sense 13

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Sides* are "side dishes"--servings of food which accompany the main dish, typically vegetables and potatoes.

In this case the customer has ordered a 'basket', which is probably a complete meal consisting of a main dish such as chicken or a sandwich with a choice of two or three *sides*. She hasn't yet made up her mind which sides she wants; since she is "watching her figure", the calorie content of different sides is an important factor.

Comment: Do you get the joke?  I don't.  It just sounds like a normal conversation.

Comment: @Kevin I don't see a joke - I don't think there is one. When I answered this the question title read "...in this conversation."

Comment: Ok, glad I'm not the only one

Comment: The "joke" is that Precious is a large woman, and in older usage women that are "watching their figures" are already skinny. Sides in a diner are probably not foods that would contribute to a skinny figure.

Comment: The joke is that sides are insignificant when compared to the original order of a basket. This is an equivalent joke to the staple joke of a person ordering a huge list of items and a diet coke since they are watching their figure.

Answer (score 8):

Side dishes, in restaurant lingo, are small portions served alongside a main dish. In many restaurants, if you order a meat entree, it comes with one or two optional "sides", which might include soup, salad, fried potatoes, or something else that traditionally accompanies the main dish.

Answer (score 2):

There's a double meaning here - sides can refer to extras that accompany the main part of the entrée, and also to her sides, the first of which can contribute to the second. The conversation leverages the double-meaning in an attempt at some humor. But...it's not side-splitting.

Comment: +1 for side-splitting, which is funnier than the "joke" :-)